# Selecting more than one value

Tags: sql, sqlite

Trying to generate a list of tracks composed by more than one person.

```
Name Composer Make
```

So it should look something like this

```
Name         composer                        Make 
Going home   Robert dennings / Don Bedge    Robert dennings , Don Bedge
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and table structures.

Comment: Please read the [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this

```
SELECT Name, Composer, REPLACE(Composer,'/',',') AS Make
FROM tracks
```

But it really is impossible to tell for sure given that you don't tell us any of the table or field names in your database and very little about your database model